# Filling blanks in a pandas dataframe column leads to reversal of function

Tags: pandas, replace, fillna

I have the following dataframe:

```
   a    b      x  y    language
0  id1  id_2   3 
1  id2  id_4   6 ,0=/%
2  id3  id_6   9 |-|/#
3  id4  id_8  12 text4
```

I used langdetect to detect the language of the text elements in column y.

This is the code I have used for that purpose:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
try:
    df.loc[i, "language"] = detect(row["y"])
except:
    continue
```

This is the result:

```
   a    b      x  y    language
0  id1  id_2   3 
1  id2  id_4   6 ,0=/%
2  id3  id_6   9 |-|/#
3  id4  id_8  12 text4  en
4  id5  id_9  14 text5  de
5  id6  id_10 12
```

I then attempted to fill the blanks in the language column with the string "N/A" using any one of the following commands:

```
df['language'].replace([''],"N/A", inplace=True)

df['language'] = df['language'].fillna(0)
```

For each command above, I received the following results:

```
      a    b    x  y    language
 0  id1  id_2   3 N/A   N/A
 1  id2  id_4   6 ,0=/% ,0=/%
 2  id3  id_6   9 |-|/# |-|/#
 3  id4  id_8  12 text4 text4  
 4  id5  id_9  14 text5 text5 
 5  id6  id_10 12 N/A   N/A
```

How do I get the following result:

```
   a    b      x  y    language
0  id1  id_2   3        N/A
1  id2  id_4   6 ,0=/%  N/A
2  id3  id_6   9 |-|/#  N/A
3  id4  id_8  12 text4  en
4  id5  id_9  14 text5  de
5  id6  id_10 12        N/A
```

Comment: do upvote the answer you found most helpful that is how community stays motivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works!

initial dataframe:

```
   a    b     x   y language new
0  0  id1  id_2   3     None    
1  1  id2  id_4   6    ,0=/%    
2  2  id3  id_6   9           kl
3  3  id4  id_8  12    text4
```

used replace just use space

```
df.new=df['new'].replace(" ",'n/a')#or

df['new'].replace(" ",'n/a',inplace=True)#also works
```

output:

```
   a    b     x   y language  new
0  0  id1  id_2   3     None  n/a
1  1  id2  id_4   6    ,0=/%  n/a
2  2  id3  id_6   9            kl
3  3  id4  id_8  12    text4  n/a
```

Comment: Thanks @gilf0yle!

Answer (score 1):

Use np where(), checking if language has an alphanumeric or not.

```
df['language']=np.where(df['language'].str.contains('\w'),df['language'],'N/A')
```

Comment: Thanks @wwnde! It worked!